# How to add Artifact metadata to nexus server

Tags: maven, metadata, pom.xml, nexus, aether

I want to know how can I add metadata for an artifact which I want to push to nexus repository.

Can I define the metadata in `POM` file. Is there any tags in pom for doing this?

If adding through `POM` is not possible what are the other ways to do this?

Comment: What kind of metadata are you talking about? Can you give an example for such meta-data?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways you can do it imho.

- Add properties right in the pom. The problem I see with that is that you can not inspect the values easily in Nexus or search on them.
- Add another file that is a properties file as an attached artifact with the Maven build helper plugin. That way they are in a separate file that can be parsed a bit easier than a Maven pom. Otherwise the same problems from 1. are there.

For both of these approaches you could create a custom Nexus plugin that shows that information somehow.

- If you are using Nexus Professional you can activate the [Custom Metadata plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/custom-metadata-plugin.html) and use the approach described on the [support site](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21474027-How-can-I-add-additional-metadata-to-an-artifact-stored-in-Nexus-) to get the properties into Nexus. Then you can also use search and so on to find specific components based on their metadata.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to add a `<properties>` tag with different properties holding your metadata.

```
<properties>
  <my.name>The King</my.name>
  <my.goal>Bring joy to my people</my.goal>
</properties>
```

You can put in anything you want and it will be in the pom put under Nexus.

I hope this helps.